# Populate dynamic values in JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js

I have a an array containing some values. I need to populate values dynamically using the array elements.
Below is the master array.

```
list = [{name: 'm1'}, {name: 'm2'},{name: 'm3'},{name: 'm4'},{name: 'm5'},]
```

I have JSON called demo.json

```
demo: {
    listCard = {
        'x': 0,
        'y': 1,
        'name': ''
    },
    layout: [
        {
            'col': '3',
            'row': '3'
            'grids': []
        }
    ]
};
```

The result should be -

```
demo: {
    listCard = {
        'x': 0,
        'y': 1,
        'name': ''
    },
    layout: [
        {
            'col': '3',
            'row': '3'
            'grids': [
                {
                    'x': 0,
                    'y': 1,
                    'name': 'm1'
                },
                {
                    'x': 0,
                    'y': 1,
                    'name': 'm2'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            'col': '3',
            'row': '3'
            'grids': [
                {
                    'x': 0,
                    'y': 1,
                    'name': 'm3'
                },
                {
                    'x': 0,
                    'y': 1,
                    'name': 'm4'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            'col': '3',
            'row': '3'
            'grids': [
                {
                    'x': 0,
                    'y': 1,
                    'name': 'm5'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

Basically the result should be like demo.listcard.name should iterate list.length times & get each value. After that layout.grid should be assigned with the whole object of listcard with 2 objects.

Below is the method I used but I am constantly failing.

```
 let listcard = demo.listcard; //here I get listcard object
 const layout = demo.layout; // layout object

const noOfScreens = (arr, size) => arr.reduce((acc, e, i) => (i % size ? acc[acc.length - 1].push(e) : acc.push([e]), acc), []);
const screens = noOfScreens(list, 2); // master array is split into arrays of size 2.

  for (let i = 0; i < screens.length; i++) {
      layout[0].grids.push(layout);
  }
```

I am stuck here. Please help me out

Comment: That's not JSON. Do you mean a *Javascript object*? Either way, its syntax is invalid…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```js
const demo = {
    listCard: {
        'x': 0,
        'y': 1,
        'name': ''
    },
    layout: []
};
const list = [{ name: 'm1' }, { name: 'm2' }, { name: 'm3' }, { name: 'm4' }, { name: 'm5' }]

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        demo.layout.push({
            'col': '3',
            'row': '3',
            'grids': [{
                'x': 0,
                'y': 1,
                'name': list[i].name
            }]
        })
    } else {
        demo.layout[Math.floor(i / 2)].grids.push({
            'x': 0,
            'y': 1,
            'name': list[i].name
        });
    }


}
console.log(demo);
```